# Loop over list of strings and perform tasks (Introducing Python Exercises Chapter 2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

where to ask if my code is clear and good.
So I have three tasks to do:

[image]

So I tried to loop through it and do all of them in a single loop.
Hope to have some feedback, have a nice one.

```
names = ['mozzarella', 'cinderella', 'salmonella']
for i in range(len(names)):
  for name in names:
    if name == 'cinderella':
        names[i] = name.capitalize()
        i += 1
    elif name == 'mozzarella':
        names[i] = name.upper()
        i += 1
    elif name == 'salmonella':
        names.remove(name)
```

Output:

```
['MOZZARELLA', 'Cinderella']
```

Comment: your `i+1` part is very brittle. what if the `salmonella` element is first?

Comment: can`t you store the results to another list ?

Comment: Can the text image be translated to actual text so it's searchable and friendly to screen readers? Thanks.

Comment: your above code may not work or will need some amendments if there more cheese elements.

Comment: @Srini Yeah, I didn't think about that
ggorlen Yeah sure.
njzk2 I think you and Srini have the same point, I am making an extra loop.
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to do two iterations here. You can do one for the `range()` and then call the list directly via `names[i]`. `i` is the current position in the range it is iterating over, so when you call `names[i]` it brings up that index within the list.

```
for i in range(len(names)):
    if names[i] == 'mozzarella': 
        names[i] = names[i].upper()
    if names[i] == 'cinderella': 
        names[i] = names[i].capitalize()
    if names[i] == 'salmonella': 
        names.remove(names[i])

names
['MOZZARELLA', 'Cinderella']
```

Comment: Yeah, totally messed up there, I "over looped" my code, I should have used only the [ i ] index and ill increase by itself.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things I would do differently (since you're asking about writing clean code, I'm addressing that, not only functional accuracy).
Generally when working on a problem that has different concerns, it's often useful to keep those concerns separate.
In this case, I'm not sure why you would want to manage all 3 concerns within the same loop.
In software, you will often find that one concern evolves at a different pace than other concerns.
Also, removing an element while you're iterating on a list is generally not a good idea. I would use something like the following:

```py
def update_cheesy(name):
    if name == 'mozzarella':
        return name.upper()
    return name

def update_person(name):
    if name == 'cinderella':
        return name.capitelize()
    return name

names[:] = [update_person(name) for name in names]
print(names)
names[:] = [update_cheesy(name) for name in names]
print(names)
names[:] = [name for name in names if name != 'salmonella']
print(names)
```

Note that the assignment is done to names[:] not names. This replaces the contents of the list, and not just sets the named reference to a different list.

You could combine all of the modifications to a single call, if you think that's cleaner.

Comment: Also @LPython - I don't think your answer will work correctly if the items you remove are not the last elements in the list.

Comment: @booooh I was trying to cover all tasks just to train my brain using loops.
But definitely your code its more optimized and cleaner.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make use of python reduce here or a simple forloop

```py
base_names = ['mozzarella', 'cinderella', 'salmonella']

# using forloop
result = []
for name in base_names:
    if name == 'salmonella':
        continue
    elif name == 'cinderella':
        name = name.capitalize()
    elif name == 'mozzarella':
        name = name.upper()
    result.append(name)
print(result)


# using reduce
from functools import reduce # for python3

def reduce_fuc(acc, name):
    if name == 'salmonella':
        return acc
    elif name == 'cinderella':
        name = name.capitalize()
    elif name == 'mozzarella':
        name = name.upper()
    acc.append(name)
    return acc

names = reduce(reduce_fuc, base_names, [])
print(names)
```

both ways returns same result but both does not modify `base_name` list but generates a new list containing the result.

Comment: Based on the requirements, it looks like they're required to mutate the list. As it specifies `Did it change the element in the list?`

Comment: @LPython ops my bad. totally missed that

Comment: Your code looks much cleaner than mine.
But I agree with LPython, looks that i wasnt allowed to use another list.
Thanks for reading my code.